# Qgis: QgsLogMessage.logMessage to output message in a specific tab

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, log

I am writing a Qgis plugin. 
I would like the plugin to write log message in a specific tab, in the Log Messages window. I tried:

```
QgsMessageLog.logMessage("File "+ii.source()+": all pixels set to no data", 'Raster Processing',QgsMessageLog.INFO )
```

but QGis keeps on writing under tab "General". I suppose I'm missing an initialisation part to instantiate a new tab and connect it to the message logger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command looks right to me, there should not be any special initialisation besides the import

```
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog
```

Maybe try with defining `tag` and `level` as defined in the [QGIS API Documentation](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMessageLog.html#a3f45208fc3b28f7e0c88e329ba120a40):

```
QgsMessageLog.logMessage("File "+ii.source()+": all pixels set to no data", tag="Raster Processing", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO )
```

Comment: In my case, using tag and level keyword allowed the function to work. I did not need to import QgsMessageLog (I'm writting a plugin, I suppose it is imported by default...).

Comment: For the QGIS 3 API, this should be `QgsMessageLog.logMessage("File all pixels set to no data", "Raster Processing", level=Qgis.Info )`